# How do you prompt a user to read a guide and restart/log off from their computer on the finished page using Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am building an installer and would like to ask the user to restart using a radio button. I would also like to include an option to open the user guide if the user selects "No, I will restart later". My current method for asking the user to open the user guide is putting it in the `[Run]` section like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\userguide.pdf"; Description: "View the User Guide"; Flags: shellexec runasoriginaluser postinstall nowait unchecked
```

This works perfectly, it even opens in the default PDF viewer. However, whenever I try to include a restart option, it overrides the user guide option and completely removes it. So, trying:

```
[Code]
function NeedRestart(): Boolean;
begin
    Result := True;
end;
```

as well as:

```
[Setup]
AlwaysRestart=yes
```

work in the sense that they include an option for restart but they also override the user guide button. Is there a way to make a custom page that, upon checking the "No I will restart later" radio button, will show an option on opening the user guide? I am not too familiar with using Inno Setup and Delphi/Pascal.

Comment: I've edited the tags used for your question, as it has nothing to do with either Delphi or Pascal. Inno Setup uses Pascalscript as its scripting language, so unless you're working directly with the source code for Inno Setup itself you're not using Delphi or Pascal. Please use only tags that actually apply to your question - tags have relevance and meaning here. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to restart after installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to code that. For example you can add your own checkbox for starting the user guide:

```
[Setup]
AlwaysRestart=yes

[Files]
Source: "userguide.pdf"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

```pascal
[Code]

var
  LaunchCheckbox: TCheckbox;

procedure YesNoRadioClicked(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Disable the user guide checkbox when "restart" is selected
  LaunchCheckbox.Enabled := WizardForm.NoRadio.Checked;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  LaunchCheckbox := TCheckbox.Create(WizardForm.FinishedPage);
  LaunchCheckbox.Caption := 'View the User Guide';
  LaunchCheckbox.Checked := False;
  LaunchCheckbox.Left := WizardForm.YesRadio.Left;
  LaunchCheckbox.Width := WizardForm.YesRadio.Width;
  LaunchCheckbox.Height := ScaleY(LaunchCheckbox.Height);
  LaunchCheckbox.Parent := WizardForm.FinishedPage;
  if (WizardForm.YesRadio.OnClick <> nil) or (WizardForm.NoRadio.OnClick <> nil) then
  begin
    Log('Restart radio button event handler unexpectedly set');
  end
    else
  begin
    WizardForm.YesRadio.OnClick := @YesNoRadioClicked;
    WizardForm.NoRadio.OnClick := @YesNoRadioClicked;
  end;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    // Adjust to the initial start of restart selection
    YesNoRadioClicked(nil);
    // Only now the restart radio buttons have their definitive vertical position
    LaunchCheckbox.Top :=
      WizardForm.NoRadio.Top + WizardForm.NoRadio.Height + ScaleY(16);
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    if (not WizardSilent) and
       (not WizardForm.YesRadio.Checked) and
       LaunchCheckbox.Checked then
    begin
      Log('Opening user guide');
      ShellExecAsOriginalUser(
        'open', ExpandConstant('{app}\userguide.pdf'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, 
        ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

---

The code assumes `AlwaysRestart`. Were the restart conditional, the code will need an update to adjust to a different layout of the *Finished* page, when restart is not needed. For a full solution see my installer for WinSCP:
https://github.com/winscp/winscp/blob/master/deployment/winscpsetup.iss